# Django ForeignKey TypeError: 'RelatedManager'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've tried to make a comment system (with comment on comment and such), but I keep getting the same error message...

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from Site.models import SiteUser


class Discussion(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=_('Title'))
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    data = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Data'))
    agree_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    tough_decision_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    disagree_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_comments(self):
        return self.comment_set.all().order_by('datetime')

    def get_comments_len(self):
        return self.comment_set.count()

    get_comments_len.allow_tags = True
    get_comments_len.short_description = _("Number of comments")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('discussion')
        verbose_name_plural = _('discussions')


class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(SiteUser, verbose_name=_('Author'), related_name='+')
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_('Time'))
    data = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Data'))
    part_of = models.ForeignKey(Discussion, verbose_name=_('Part of'), related_name='comments')
    on = models.ForeignKey('self', verbose_name=_('On'), related_name='child', blank=True, null=True)
    agree_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    tough_decision_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    disagree_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.data

    def get_child_comment(self):
        return self.child()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('comment')
        verbose_name_plural = _('comments')
```

Every time I try to access the Comment from itself (via "child"), I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'RelatedManager' object is not callable
```

Help!

Comment: What a shame you didn't think it appropriate to include the actual syntax you're using when you "access the comment from itself".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `child` attribute is a manager (`RelatedManager`). To query it, you should call `.all()`, for instance.

```
def get_child_comment(self):
    return self.child.all()
```